# How to find out aspx of webpage

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible that when I right click inside a **webpage** and go to **Properties** I see in the **URL address** `..../COMPANIES/Companies.aspx?mode=INIT` but in reality it's a different aspx (`..../US_COMPANIES/US_Companies.aspx?mode=INIT`)?

Side note: The reason why I ask this is that I looked into the .cs page (Companies.aspx.cs according to Properties) but I didn't find the method definitions I was expecting to see, but I did find them in US_Companies.aspx.cs.

If there is enough detail in this question to make reasonable assumptions, I thank you. Please revert if I can make my question clearer. I am in the process of picking up a new project (inherited). Thanks a lot.

So the main question is how to find out for certain the aspx of a webpage and is it possible it's not always straight forward? Newbie in ASP.NET here.

Comment: could there be url rewriting in place? if so you have to follow that down the rabbit hole.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that, Daniel. How could I go about checking if there is URL rewriting?

Comment: you will have to check your web server.

Comment: What is your recommendation on what to check and where to start? Could this be put plainly in a few words with upfront tips that can help me unroll and add strength to a well-conducted investigation? Thanks.